# business continuity management keeping a site collection as readonly off site

Tags: export, replication

We have an interanl SharePoint Farm. One of the site collection is for business continuity management. As parth of BCM we need to host a version of the site off site, on differnt hardware. Is it possible to export the site content of the site as static pages and html documents that we can stick else where?

Can you mirror a site collection? The external site can be read only. Just need the documents. Can anyone recomend waht they would think of doing?

Comment: What specific version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: 2010 Standard edition

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it - you can do SQL Database mirroring of content Databases, so in the case of disaster you can point your DR servers to the mirrored database and keep working.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx

There is also a content publishing feature which will publish content between farms so you can deploy the content to another farm.  This can be used to expose select content to the Internet, and also for high availability.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanz/archive/2009/02/02/how-to-publish-sharepoint-content-from-an-authoring-farm-inside-corporate-network-to-a-production-farm-in-dmz.aspx

Depending on your availability requirements you may want a simple batch job which gets a nightly SQL backup, copies it to your DR DB server, restores it and sets it to readonly.